# Failing to get a List<> of objects after a LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to convert my the result of my LINQ query to a list, but without a success until now.

```
This is my action method : 

public ActionResult DisplayListOfRolesUser()
{              
    string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();//get the id of the logged user

    UserDetails userDetails = db.UsersDetails.Where(c => c.identtyUserId == currentUserId)
    .FirstOrDefault();
    int UsrCompanyId = userDetails.CompanyId;//get the user's company

     List<WorkRole> WorkRolesQuery = db.WorkRoles.Where(c => c.CompanyId == UsrCompanyId)
     .FirstOrDefault().ToList();//get all the work roles for the compnay.

     //List<WorkRole> lst = WorkRolesQuery.ToList();

     return View(lst);
}
```

I tried many answers from stack overflow, but without success.

Currently `List<WorkRole> WorkRolesQuery = db.WorkRoles.Where(c => c.CompanyId == UsrCompanyId).FirstOrDefault().ToList();`

ToList is underlined with red and it says 'WorkRole' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'.

I simply want to have a list of `WorkRole` objects so I can display them in my view in some form.

Can somebody help?

Here is my model as well :

```
public class WorkRole
{
    [Key]

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int WorkRoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string RoleDescription { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkRolesUsersDetails> WorkRolesUsersDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `.FirstOrDefault().ToList();`, this means that you first select the first item (if existing, null otherwise) and then try to convert this one item to a list (which fails).
Simply calling `ToList()` after the `Where()` statement should do it:

```
List<WorkRole> WorkRolesQuery = db.WorkRoles.Where(c => c.CompanyId == UsrCompanyId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You try to get first element (only one element) calling `FirstOrDefault()`  and cast it to list.

Replace this line:

```
List<WorkRole> WorkRolesQuery = 
               db.WorkRoles
               .Where(c => c.CompanyId == UsrCompanyId)
               .FirstOrDefault()
               .ToList();
```

by this:

```
List<WorkRole> WorkRolesQuery = 
               db.WorkRoles
               .Where(c => c.CompanyId == UsrCompanyId)
               .ToList();      // without FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 2):

`FirstOrDefault` returns just the very first instance of type `WorkRole` whose `CompanyId` is equal to your `UsrCompanyId`, not an entire list. So you can´t call `ToList` on that instance. I suppose you can omit the call to `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var WorkRolesQuery = db.WorkRoles
    .Where(c => c.CompanyId == UsrCompanyId)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is ...

```
List<WorkRole> WorkRolesQuery = db.WorkRoles.Where(c => c.CompanyId == UsrCompanyId).ToList();
```

As FirstOrDefault returns a single entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ToList()` because `FirstOrDefault()` returns one item or null. If you are expecting more than one item to be returned, use `While()` and then `ToList()`, don't use `FirstOrDefault()`.

```
var WorkRoles = db.WorkRoles.Where(c => c.CompanyId == UsrCompanyId).ToList();
```

Also note if you are using `FirstOrDefault()`, you can simply pass in the condition without having to use `Where()`.

```
var WorkRole = db.WorkRoles.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyId == UsrCompanyId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
List<WorkRole> WorkRolesQuery = new List<WorkRole>(db.WorkRoles
.Where(c => c.CompanyId == UsrCompanyId));
```